# JavaScript Protoype confusion

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am new to JavaScript and experimenting with it these days. I came to know that JavaScript is prototype based. I tried executing below code:

```
var Person = function(name) {   
    this.name = name;
}
alert(Person.prototype);
var ram = new Person("Ram"); 
alert(ram.prototype);
```

As expected, the first alert prints **[object, Object]**, I expect the second alert prints the same, but it doesn't, why?

Can any please explain it clearly?

Comment: Try `ram.constructor` and `ram.constructor.prototype`

Comment: ram doesn't have a prototype .. :P

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7929569 for an answer to a similar question

Answer (score 3):

Because the `prototype` property on functions **isn't** the function's prototype, it's a property that will get used to set the prototype of objects created via the `new` operator with that function.

You can access the object's prototype using ES5's `Object.getPrototypeOf`:

```
var Person = function(name) {   
    this.name = name;
};
alert(Person.prototype);
var ram = new Person("Ram"); 
alert(Object.getPrototypeOf(ram));
```

On Firefox and several other browsers, you can use an upcoming ES6 feature (for JavaScript in browsers): The `__proto__` accessor property:

```
var Person = function(name) {   
    this.name = name;
};
alert(Person.prototype);
var ram = new Person("Ram"); 
alert(ram.__proto__);        // ES6 feature, but already fairly common
```

---

Note that `__proto__` is a property inherited from `Object.prototype`, so if you create an object that doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype` (e.g., `var o = Object.create(null);` or anything using that `o` as a prototype), you can only use `Object.getPrototypeOf`, not `__proto__`.

Answer (score 0):

The `prototype` property of your object `Person` is a property that you will only find in **functions**. To be clear, in JavaScript, *functions* are also *objects* with their own *prototype*. However, *functions* also have a special property named `prototype` which will become the *prototype* of every object made with that function as constructor.