# Javascript prototype only made with functions not object literals

Tags: javascript

Researching a bit more deeper in Object creation and prototypes. What confused me was the following, which I could not find information about.

If we have the following code:

```
Dog.prototype.bark = "woof";
function Dog (name){
    this.name = name;
}


function foo (){
    console.log('test');
}

let bar = {};

console.log(Dog.prototype);
console.log(foo.prototype);
console.log(bar.prototype);
```

we get the following output (chrome dev tools):

[image: prototypes javascript objects]

Why do only functions have prototypes implicitly created prototypes?

Comment: Cause functions are constructors in js. Objects arent. You can call `new foo()` but not `new f`. And dont mix `.prototype` and *The Prototype*

Comment: To add on to Jonas' comment: `new foo()` or `new Dog()` are valid, however, `new {}` is not. This is because functions implicitly act as constructors when called with the `new` keyword. An object literal is an *instance* of an `Object`, not the `Object` constructor itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a new object in Javascript have a prototype property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929159/does-a-new-object-in-javascript-have-a-prototype-property)

Comment: if you change the last line to `console.log(bar.__proto__);` you can see the actual object prototype.